# Enable mongodb authentication by mongod.conf without restart

Tags: mongodb

I want add username and password into mongod.conf, and start `mongod` with authentication enabled. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

no this is not possible...

> ***Re-start*** the MongoDB instance with access control. Re-start the
>   mongod instance with the `--auth` command line option or, if using a
>   configuration file, the security.authorization setting.

```
mongod --auth --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db1
```